# How do I change phpMyAdmin access URL?

Tags: apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

Could someone please tell me how to change phpMyAdmin's access URL, I would like it only to be accessible from a specific URL: **database.example.com**. example.com would be replaced to my actual domain.

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with LAMP and phpMyAdmin installed. I installed phpMyAdmin through command line using:

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Many Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ubuntu (i used ubuntu 12.04), the default phpmyadmin apache configuration can be found at `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

You can open it by type `sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and change the third

```
Alias /yournewalias /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Do not forget to restart apache service,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: after change alias, _reload_ apache2 conf is enough !-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used, check out the comments as well!
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-change-phpmyadmin-access-url

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.