# change phpmyadmin url through /etc/apache2/conf-available.phpmyadmin.conf

Tags: server, apache2, phpmyadmin

I am using ubuntu **16.04** hosted in digital ocean

I want to change phpmyadmin access url. I saw [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796932/how-do-i-change-phpmyadmin-access-url) but they gave 2 options :

1) /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf  - I tried, no luck.

2) /etc/apache2/conf-available/**phpmyadmin.conf** , but here instead of conf file type, its displaying as `Readbale folder` what wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change phpMyAdmin port from 80 to another number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896988/change-phpmyadmin-port-from-80-to-another-number) also [How to secure phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938398/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin)

Comment: @pa4080 Thanks for your comment, i went through that link, i dont want to change the port but i want to change phpmyadmin access url path......

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up the links. The first one can give you a general view to the configuration of `phpmyadmin`. The [first part of the second one](https://askubuntu.com/a/939241/566421) should be that you are looking for. I will write a short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`, that is displayed as 'folder', is a [symbolic link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/symlink.7.html) to `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`:

```bsh
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 яну 20  2017 /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf -> ../../phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

To change the URI (access path) of PhpMyAdmin. Edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and change the first path (`/phpmyadmin`) of this directive:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

- Explanation about the directive [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html). Let's assume that `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html`. In this case the directive `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` will serve as this symlink:

  ```
  ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
  ```

References:

- [How to secure phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938398/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin)
- [Change phpMyAdmin port from 80 to another number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896988/change-phpmyadmin-port-from-80-to-another-number) (here are explained the basics about the default the configuration)

---

**Update from the discussion:** Indeed `phpmyadmin.conf` wasn't enabled, because the symbolic link `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` was missing. PhpMyAdmin was enabled within Apache's configuration by [a symbolic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW7nj.png), created in `/var/www/html`, exactly as the above example. So the steps we perform were:

- Tweak the `Alias` directive in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`;
- Enable `phpmyadmin.conf`: `sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf`;
- Restart Apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`;
- Check whether the new URI path works;
- Remove the unnecessary symbolic link: `sudo rm /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Thanks, i checked as here : http://prntscr.com/h283x5 , before only i edited here : `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`, but that did't worked for me.....

Comment: @spylh9999ggr: Did you restart Apache after the change?

Comment: yes, i restarted.....

Comment: @spylh9999ggr: How do you install `phpmyadmin`? Via `apt` or you've used some other method?

Comment: i used these commands : `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`

Comment: @spylh9999ggr: Maybe you have another directive related to `phpmyadmin` somewhere within your configuration - `apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` - that makes mess. Is `phpmyadmin.conf` exist in the directory `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`?

Comment: there is no phpmyadmin directory in path : `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`

Comment: also i have directory  `000-default.conf` under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67695/discussion-between-spylh9999ggr-and-pa4080).